# Does the executive branch have its own form of contempt?

Tags: united-states, executive

The Judicial Branch has [Contempt of Court](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court) as described below:

> Contempt of court, often referred to simply as "contempt", is the offense of being disobedient to or discourteous toward a court of law and its officers in the form of behavior that opposes or defies the authority, justice and dignity of the court.

The Legislative Branch also has its own form of contempt called [Contempt of Congress](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_Congress) as described below:

> Contempt of Congress is the act of obstructing the work of the United States Congress or one of its committees.

Does Contempt also exist in some manner for the Executive branch as well?

Comment: God help all of us if contempt for bureaucracy ever becomes a crime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no such thing as "contempt of the executive branch."

There are various laws that require compliance with the orders and requests of executive branch officials at various times, some of which can provide a basis for detention or arrest.

But, even then, if someone fails to comply the ordinary process is to file a court proceeding and to seek an order in the court. After a court grants that order, failure to comply is contempt of court.